# jQuery problem selecting text only from table cell when there is an image

Tags: html, jquery, web-scraping, html-table, cheerio

I'm using jQuery (well, cheerio) to scrape data from an html table. I'm trying to display data from one column that has text as well as an image in the cell, but I only want it to display the text.

for example the table looks like:

```
col 1          | col 2     | col 3
---------------------------------------
data 1-1 [img] | data 1-2  | data 1-3 
data 2-1 [img] | data 2-2  | data 2-3 
data 3-1 [img] | data 3-2  | data 3-3 
data 4-1 [img] | data 4-2  | data 4-3
```

When I select like this: `$(this).children().next().text()` it outputs everything in that row, like this: `data 1-1 data 1-2 data 1-3`

It works when I do `$(this).children().next().html()` but then the output is this: `data 1-1 <img src="blah.jpg">`, obviously because it's including the html of the image in that column.

How do I get it to only select `data 1-1` without including the img or the rest of that row?

I'm very new to jQuery so I've been having a hard time with this. Apologies if this question was already asked, I couldn't find anything about it...I've left out some code for simplicity but let me know if you'd like to see the entire function

**UPDATE: ANSWER**

Thank you to Roko for the help, here is the solution implemented with my full code (i used `.eq(0)` instead of `tr:eq(0)` because I'm using [cheerio](https://github.com/watson/cheerio-eq))

```js
router.get("/scrape", function(req, res){
    request("http://link-goes-here", function(error, response, html){
        var $ = cheerio.load(html);
        var storeInfo = [];
        $("body > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > table").addClass("row");
        //loop through selected table only where tr = "QA1"
        $('.row > tbody > tr:contains("QA1")').each(function(i, element){
            var result = {
                "environment" : $(this).children().next().eq(0).text(),
                "store" : $(this).children().next().next().html(),
                "version" : $(this).children().next().next().next().html()
            };
            storeInfo.push(result);
        });
    });
    res.redirect("/stores");
});
```

Comment: What context is `$(this)` in your code?

Comment: Post your code so we can see what the context is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`:eq()` selector](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)  or the [`.eq()` method](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get a specific Row index and than a specific cell index.

**Example** getting the `.text()` of the TBODY's first TR `:eq(0)` and its first TD `:eq(0)`

```js
const val = $("#someTable").find("tbody tr:eq(0) td:eq(0)").text();
console.log(val);   // "data 1-1"
```

```html
<table id="someTable">
<thead>
  <tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr><td>data 1-1 <img src="//placehold.it/50x50"></td><td>data 1-2</td><td>data 1-3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 2-1 <img src="//placehold.it/50x50"></td><td>data 2-2</td><td>data 2-3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 3-1 <img src="//placehold.it/50x50"></td><td>data 3-2</td><td>data 3-3</td></tr>
  <tr><td>data 4-1 <img src="//placehold.it/50x50"></td><td>data 4-2</td><td>data 4-3</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

To get the second row's first cell simply use `tr:eq(1)` and `td:eq(0)`. And so on

Comment: This worked great! Thank you so much! Sorry for not getting back sooner...